# load more then one category id

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

How to load more then one category id

```
$categoryIds = array(957);
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->joinField(
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'product_id=entity_id',
                        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                        'left'
                )
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 0));
//->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED))
```

Comment: why you do not use Magento products collection by multiple category id concept?

Comment: No actually for some reason i used particular category only

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different approach. Rather than loading a lot of categories, you could load the product collection and then filter by categories

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);

$products->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
);

$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(32,5)));

foreach ($products as $product) {

}
```